# How many ways are there to change a variable's value?

Tags: python, variables

In Python, if you want to **change a variable's value**, there are multiple ways:

```
foo = 1               # By assignment
bar.func()            # By calling its method.
for baz in range(5):  # By "leaking" from a loop
```

Just out of curiosity, I want to find every way to achieve this goal in a "normal" program. By "normal" I mean not directly manipulating `locals()` or do similar things.

Also I know there's some discussion around whether Python has real "variable", but let's not focus on that for this question.

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos Any suggestions on where to ask?

Comment: Passing a variable to a function doesn't change its value. And a `for` loop is just another form of an assignment.

Comment: Sorry @laik9m I misread your question deleted my comment

Comment: @Aran-Fey ok so there's only assignment?

Comment: Anything that's not an assignment probably wouldn't be considered a "normal program".

Comment: You can mutate the  `globals()` and `locals()` dictionaries if you are looking for edge cases

Comment: @Aran-Fey Actually I missed calling method. Modified question.

Comment: Wait a minute, mutating the variable's value also counts? So things like `del foo[0]` or `foo.update(x=3)` or `next(foo)` or `foo.append(7)` all count?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I know, and those cases are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes they count, and I believe they can be categorized as "calling the object's method" cause internally they are.

Comment: "Calling its method" *doesn't* inherently change the value at all; it's only something done in/by that method that modifies the value. Which is to say, if you're looking for primitives (operations that everything else boils down to), method calls aren't in the set. And if you're *not* looking for primitives, it's next to impossible without mind reading to know what is or isn't in-scope for this question.

Comment: ...for that matter, there are different things being conflated here. `foo = 1` is creating a new binding called `foo`, to a pre-existing / previously-interned value. `for baz in range(5)` is similarly creating new bindings to the name `baz`... whereas `bar.func()` is presumably modifying the state of `bar` in-place (if it makes any changes at all); it notably **doesn't** change what object the name `bar` is bound to; it just may (or may not) modify the state of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's really not clear what "change a variable's value" means to you.  Python objects have state, so you can coherently ask which methods may mutate an object's state, and names in Python can be bound to objects, so you can coherently ask how such bindings can change.

For the former, it depends on the type of the object.  For the latter, see section 4.2.1 ("Binding of names") in the Python Language Reference Manual:

> The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions, `import` statements, class and function definitions (these bind the class or function name in the defining block), and targets that are identifiers if occurring in an assignment, `for` loop header, or after `as` in a `with` statement or `except` clause. The `import` statement of the form `from ... import *` binds all names defined in the imported module, except those beginning with an underscore. This form may only be used at the module level.
>
> A target occurring in a `del` statement is also considered bound for this purpose (though the actual semantics are to unbind the name).

Comment: thanks, that's helpful.